# Rigging: Is there a shortcut for reseting a single bone rotation?

Tags: armature, bones

How can I reset a single bone's rotation, what is the shortcut?

Comment: in Edit mode or Pose mode?

Comment: You can reset the transform by holding "ALT" and press the transform's shortcut. (In this case "R").

Comment: Thanks. ALT+R works.